# Why the difference in fundamental solutions?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Finding [a fundamental solution of a linear differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution)
$f''-c^2f$, I try in 12.3.1 on Windows 10

```
DSolve[f''[x] - c^2*f[x] == DiracDelta[x - y], f[x], x]
```

> `{{f[x] ->    E^(c x) C[1] + E^(-c x) C[2] - ( E^(-c x - c y) (-E^(2 c x) + E^(2 c y)) HeavisideTheta[x - y])/( 2 c)}}`

To be sure, I also execute (following the documentation to `DiracDelta`, namely the "Properties" section,
and [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function))

```
DSolve[f''[x] - c^2*f[x] == DiracDelta[-x + y], f[x], x]
```

> `{{f[x] ->  E^(c x) C[1] + E^(-c x) C[2] +  E^(-c x) (E^(2 c x) Inactive[Integrate][(E^(-c K[1]) DiracDelta[y - K[1]])/( 2 c), {K[1], 1, x}] +  Inactive[Integrate][-((E^(c K[2]) DiracDelta[y - K[2]])/( 2 c)), {K[2], 1, x}])}}`

Which of these different results is correct?

Comment: The first one is the correct one , I think. The second solution is a general solution, which Mathematica couldn't evaluate further. May be because Mathematica doesn't recognize the symmetrie of DiracDelta: `DiracDela[x]== DiracDelta[-x] ->True ` but `DiracDela[x-y]== DiracDelta[y-x] ->unevaluated `

Comment: My unsuccessful attempt is `DSolve[f''[x] - c^2*f[x] == eps/Pi/(eps^2 + (x - y)^2), f[x], x]` and then `eps` tends to zero from above. The result is `E^(c x) C[1] + E^(-c x) C[2]`.

Comment: The weak limit differs from the usual notion of the limit.

Comment: Your "unsuccessful attempt" gives a solution, similar to your first solution in your question. But last step `eps->0` is not alowed!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: You wrote 'Your "unsuccessful attempt" gives a solution, similar to your first solution in your question'. Sorry. I don't see that.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Your guess "May be because Mathematica doesn't recognize the symmetrie of `DiracDelta: DiracDela[x]== DiracDelta[-x] ->True`  but `DiracDela[x-y]== DiracDelta[y-x] ->unevaluated` " is very doubtful, since the outputs of `DSolve[f''[x] - c^2*f[x] == DiracDelta[x - I], f[x], x]` and `DSolve[f''[x] - c^2*f[x] == DiracDelta[I - x], f[x], x]`  (`I` is the imaginary unit) are identical ( both are wrong).

Comment: Nothing doubtful: `real x,y `

Comment: First, by default `y` is not assumed to be real. Second, the same issue with `DiracDelta[x-2]` and `DiracDelta[2-x]`. --ad personam content removed by a mod--

Comment: Your last "personal" hint is misplaced, completely unnecessary and completely unfounded! Like many other users  too in the stackexchange community I'll stop my contributions to your questions completely!

Answer (score 1):

To long for a comment:

Assuming `c==1` the first solution follows to

```
sol1=DSolve[{f''[x] - f[x] == DiracDelta[x - y] }, f ,x][[1, 1]][[2, 2]] /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0}
```

Your "unsuccessful attempt"  gives

```
eps =.
F = Function[{x, y, eps}, Evaluate[DSolve[{f''[x] -  f[x] == eps/Pi/(eps^2 + (x - y)^2), f[0] == 0 }, f , x][[1, 1]][[2, 2]] /. {C[1] -> 0,  C[2] -> 0}]]
```

Plot of both solutions

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[{sol1, Boole[x > y] F[x,y, .1]}], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0,3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

shows quite good approximation.

Comment: You wrote "shows quite good approximation". Can you elaborate it? What exactly  is well approximated?

Comment: Do you put `eps=0.0;`? The result of `eps=.;` is `eps`.

Comment: I find your "too long for acomment" very similar to [that answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257350/incorrect-results-of-dsolve) .

Comment: I added the plot command with `eps=.1`.

Comment: Thank you. Still don't understand all that `[[1, 1]][[2, 2]]`  and see "a good approximation".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your second solution is missing the HeavisideTheta factor in the second solution, but it is fairly straightforward to show your first solution satisfies the differential equation.

```
eq=f''[x]-c^2*f[x]==DiracDelta[x-y]

DSolve[eq,f[x],x]//Flatten

(*   {f[x] -> C[1]*E^(c*x) + C[2]/E^(c*x) - (E^(-(c*x) - c*y)*(E^(2*c*y) - E^(2*c*x))*
      HeavisideTheta[x - y])/(2*c)}   *)

f[x_]=f[x]/.%
```

Plug the result into the equation to test our solution.

```
eq = eq//Simplify

(*   2*E^(c*(x - y))*DiracDelta[x - y] + (E^(c*(y - x)) - E^(c*(x - y)))*
    DiracDelta[x - y] + ((E^(2*c*x) - E^(2*c*y))*
     Derivative[1][DiracDelta][x - y])/(E^(c*(x + y))*(2*c)) == 
  DiracDelta[x - y]   *)
```

It looks like we do not have a match, but realizing that DiracDelta's only mean something inside an integral, we multiply each side by `g[x]` and integrate:

```
Integrate[eq[[1]]*g[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == Integrate[eq[[2]]*g[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(*   ConditionalExpression[True, Element[y, Reals]]  *)
```

So the result satisfies the differential equation at least in the case of real `y`.

Doing the integrals by hand, I agree with Mathematica for the above.  In the case of your second answer, doing the integrals by hand and assuming `y` lies inside the limits of integration I get the same result as the first solution except that it is missing the `HeavisideTheta` factor.  The two solutions should be the same.

Comment: Thank you for your work which confirms that the implementation of the $\delta$-distribution in Mathematica leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Replacing `eq=f''[x]-c^2*f[x]==DiracDelta[x-y]` by `eq=f''[x]-c^2*f[x]==DiracDelta[y-x]` and executing the rest of your code without any changes, I obtain `ConditionalExpression[True, y \[Element] Reals]` .

Comment: Moreover, `ClearAll[f,x,y]; eq1 = f''[x] - c^2*f[x] == DiracDelta[x - y];
eq2 = f''[x] - c^2*f[x] == DiracDelta[y - x];
DSolve[eq2, f[x], x] // Flatten;


f[x_] = f[x] /. %;eq1 = eq1 // Simplify;Integrate[eq1[[1]]*g[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 
 Integrate[eq1[[2]]*g[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` produces `ConditionalExpression[True, y \[Element] Reals]`, This means that the weak solution of `eq2` is the weak solution of `eq1`. I repeat that `Integrate[(E^(-c K[1]) DiracDelta[y - K[1]])/( 2 c), {K[1], 1, x}] ` makes no sense in traditional math.

Comment: I really do not understand why you can't do that integral.  It is in the standard form given in all the books covering DiracDelta integrals.  `Integrate[f[x] DiracDelta[a-x] dx`.  The value is `f[a]` if a is contained in the integration limits, and zero otherwise.  For your integral the value is `Exp[-c y]/(2 c)` for y between `1` and `x`.  If `y` is outside those values, the value is zero, and the user must actually use knowledge of the situation if `y` is either `1` or `x`.